# Where to use WHERE clause in this query?

Tags: sql

I want only results `WHERE COUNT = 0`, but every way I tried making this query it failed. Please help!

```
SELECT 
    username, 
    COUNT(user_id) AS COUNT 
FROM 
    users 
LEFT JOIN 
    photos ON users.id = photos.user_id 
GROUP BY 
    username 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT ASC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HAVING`. For example:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(user_id) AS COUNT 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN photos ON users.id = photos.user_id 
GROUP BY username 
HAVING COUNT = 0
ORDER BY COUNT ASC;
```

`HAVING` filters "resulting rows" after they are aggregated. `WHERE`, on the other side, filters rows before they are aggregated.

Or... you can use an *anti-join*:

```
select u.username from users u
left join photos p on u.id = p.user_id 
where p.user_id is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only interested in users without and photos you don't actually need to *count* anything:

```
select username
from users u
where not exists (select * from photos p where p.user_id = u.id);
```